# how to encrypt vpnc Xauth password in /etc/vpn/example.cfg file?

Tags: encryption, ubuntu, configuration-files, vpn, openvpn

when i set up vpnc, i created a /etc/vpnc/example.cfg file so that i don't have to enter everything every time.

one of the lines is "Xauth password " where i have to enter it in plain text. is there a way to encrypt it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an obfuscated password.
Use `Xauth obfuscated password XXXXXX`.

Remember that the obfuscated password can be deobfuscated with the `cisco-decrypt` utility.

You can create the obfuscated password with the `cisco-encrypt` tool, which you can build using the code provided [here](https://github.com/coldfix/cisco-encrypt).

Do this like

```
gcc -o cisco-encrypt cisco-encrypt.c -lgcrypt
```

(requires libgcrypt)

Comment: Anyhow, one extra layer gives one extra bit of security. However, I wonder why CISCO did not use a stronger encryption.